# How to fill a vector with typeid's from variadic template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, typeid

```
std::vector<std::type_index> vec;

template <typename T1, typename... Tn>
void Fill() {
    vec.push_back(typeid(T1));
    // fill the vector with the remaining type ids
}
```

I want to fill the vector with the `typeid`s of the template arguments. How could I implement this?

Comment: This question may be related to your problem: [**Creating an array initializer from a tuple or variadic template parameters**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251815/creating-an-array-initializer-from-a-tuple-or-variadic-template-parameters). Note that the templated parameters are evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following solution uses intializer list:

```
template <typename... Types>
void Fill(std::vector<std::type_index>& vec)
{
    vec.insert(vec.end(), {typeid(Types)...});
}
```

See [live example](http://ideone.com/yjfamm).

Comment: This seems to be the shortest and most effective solution.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
template<typename T>
void Fill() {
    vec.push_back(typeid(T));
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Tn>
void Fill() {
    Fill<T1>();
    Fill<T2, Tn...>();
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/609a18267ae8faba)

Answer (score 2):

Implement it using recursion:

```
std::vector<std::type_index> vec;

template<typename T>
void fill(){
    vec.emplace_back(typeid(T)); // pretty sure you want emplace_back here ;)
}

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename ... Tn>
void fill(){
    fill<T1>();
    fill<T2, Tn...>();
}
```

I think this will do what you want.

Comment: I really don't understand why you had to downvote though, just a comment would have been far more constructive :/

Comment: If you are referring to me: I didn't downvote. In fact I just got a downvote myself which I don't understand. (I just checked: You don't have a downvote. You have 1 upvote and 0 downvotes!)

Comment: Oh, my bad then, still don't get the down-vote though

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Which downvote? I just retracted my former upvote, in favor of the other answer.

Comment: @DanielFrey no. filler sentence.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode OK, so in case of doubt I'll believe you that you downvoted someone else today.

Comment: Why would I lie about that -_- I down-voted the question, but not your answer.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode And what was this meant to be?? (flagged as not constructive ...)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What do you mean? This was the first answer to the question. I did edit it later to correct it though, as Daniel pointed out to me

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Downvoting the question is free and therefore doesn't explain why your reputation was 409 yesterday and it's 428 now. You downvoted an answer today, that's why I was suspicious if it was my answer... sorry if I jumped to the wrong conclusion.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it was satire. Geez, sometimes the community is pretty stiff here :L

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Hmmm, satire or not may lie in the eye of the viewer. Be a bit cautios with such. I'm not that _stiff_ as you might think I am ;) ...