# Writing a template-based factory system

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, factory

I have written a template-based factory system for a project I'm working on. These are the signatures for some of the function templates I have:

```
template <typename Interface, typename... Args>
void register_factory(identifier id, function<shared_ptr<Interface> (Args...)> factory);

template <typename Interface, typename... Args>
void unregister_factory(identifier id);

template <typename Interface, typename... Args>
shared_ptr<Interface> create(identifier id, Args... args);
```

As you see, I have to give all my function templates a `typename... Args` argument, because I need to access the variables in which I store factory functions:

```
template <typename Interface, typename... Args>
struct factory_storage {
  static map<identifier, function<shared_ptr<Interface> (Args...)> factories;
};
```

But logically, I should only need those for `register_factory` and `create`, everywhere else knowing `Interface` should suffice (all factory functions for the same interface have the same signature). In fact, if I had used `void*` instead of `std::function`, I could have gotten rid of most occurrences of `typename... Args` in my code.

Is there a way I could keep the type-safety of `std::function` and also avoid some of the clutter. I've seen `std::tuple` used for storing `typename...` arguments, and those could be one possible solution to my problem, but they seem overly complicated and I'm hoping to be able to avoid them.

Comment: [This may be related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251815/creating-an-array-initializer-from-a-tuple-or-variadic-template-parameters), I used it to solve a similar problem.

Comment: As the user have to remember the matching between `id` and `Args` type, does it make sense to return a template class ID based on `Interface` and `Args` instead of simple `identifier id` ?

Comment: I need to make an `std::function<Interface>(Args...)` function type in any case. How could I construct that type if I don't receive Interface and Args as template arguments?

Comment: @Elektito: I mean if `id` was something like `identifier<Interface, Args...>`, the template arguments you want can be deduced from `id`.

Comment: That might be possible, but `identifier` here is an int typedef, widely used throughout the code for various purposes. I'd need to change a lot of code to make it like this.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of signature of `std::function` are fixed, a `variant` (as the one from [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html)) is a possible solution.

Comment: That is not the case, I'm afraid. This is a library, and I have no control over how it is going to be used later.