# Write macro as c++ function

Tags: c++, macros

I have this macro for start packet's

```
#define BEGIN_PACKET_DEF(name, type) typedef struct name {\
int8_t header;\
static size_t size() { return sizeof(name); }\
name() { memset(this, 0, sizeof(name)); header = type; }
```

And this for ending packet's

```
#define END_PACKET_DEF(name) } name;
```

And i want to change it as a c++ function.
As name says is an define to start packet definition 
The `BEGIN_PACKET_DEF` will add auto the `int8_t header;` in each packet

Example usage :

```
    BEGIN_PACKET_DEF(Name_struct,HEADER)
 // some packet's data
   END_PACKET_DEF(Name_packet)
```

I need some help to rewrite those macro as C++ functions and to do same effect like macros, I just don't like to use macros.

Comment: One hint might be to ask your compiler to show the source text after preprocessing - as this contains the expanded macros ...

Answer (score 2):

> I just don't like to use macros.

This kind of `BEGIN_` `END_` type macro pairs is one of their rare valid uses, and you generally can't replace them with functions to achieve the same effect.

---

The closest you can get in c++ without a macro, is to define a variadic template struct, that forwards the type parameters to a `std::tuple`. You can see my [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251815/creating-an-array-initializer-from-a-tuple-or-variadic-template-parameters)<sup>1</sup> here how that can be done.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Don't care about the downvotes, the question was valid, and the answer was good. Actually that had been used to go in production.</sub>