# Is there a way to convert tuple to another tuple with different item type?

Tags: c++11, stdtuple

Is it possible to convert all `std::string` items inside a tuple to `const char*`?

```
template<typename... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...> tup
```

The problem I facing is I try to print a variadic template to file

```
fprintf(file, std::get<Idx>(tup)...)
```

the first item in tup is the format string (`const char*` for sure), the rest are print args. The args may contain `std::string`. The problem is that `fprintf` does not take `std::string`. How do I convert all `std::string` inside the tuple to `const char*` and form another tuple?

The `tup` will not go out scope before finish the print.

Comment: What should the lifetime of those `const char*`s be? Should they be destroyed along with the `std::string`? Should they be dynamically allocated and then deleted at some point?

Comment: @TartanLlama I just update my question, that is the problem I am facing.

Comment: Perhaps this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820104/equivalent-of-stdtransform-for-tuples or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235246/transform-variadic-template-parameters-to-another-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we're just `fprint`-ing the tuple, that's not so much *converting* the tuple as just passing it into something else. We can use the index sequence trick to pull out the individual components:

```
template <class... Ts>
void fprintf_tuple(FILE* file, std::tuple<Ts...> const& tuple) {
    fprintf_tuple(file, tuple, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{});
}
```

Once we have the individual components, we just need a converter:

```
template <class T> T const& convert_for_printing(T const& val) { return val; }
const char* convert_for_printing(std::string const& val) { return val.c_str(); }
```

And then call that on everything:

```
template <class... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
void fprintf_tuple(FILE* file, std::tuple<Ts...> const& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...> )
{
    fprintf(file, 
        convert_for_printing(std::get<Is>(tuple))...
        );
}
```